# VM in Read-Only - no commands executed

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, root, read-only

A Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server VM has entered Read-Only Mode, to the point that basic commands such as `ls` are not executed anymore, and return the error message  `-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Input/output error`, even for root.

A Read-only state is usually fixed by executing a disk check (`fsck`) or remounting the partitions (`remount`), but none of these commands can be called.

It being a VM, booting from an external disk is not an option.

At present, there is connectivity over ssh to the VM, but I fear the connectivity will be lost after a reboot.
Does anyone have any idea of something to try, before rebooting as a last resort?

Thanks

Comment: boot from a rescue disc

Comment: ...and have your backups ready. This is not so much "read-only mode" as "having a corrupted filesystem". Depending on how badly the filesystem is damaged, `fsck` might not be able to repair all the damage. Also, it might worth figuring out what caused the corruption in the first place.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - rescue disk is not an option, but thanks.

Comment: @Lacek Indeed, I quite agree, it's a filesystem issue. But it happened on a VM deployed on a range for which I'm not administrator. Being about the lowest in the hierarchy of the pack, I just have to suck it up .. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
After further degradation of the state of the machine, nothing was possible but to reboot.
After reboot, fsck was accessible, and fixed the most pregnant issue.
So -> reboot, fsck.